# How to left join with Arel?

Tags: ruby, join, arel

Arel 3.0.2 provides two classes to specify the join type: `Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin` and `Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin` and uses `InnerJoin` as default.

```
foo = Arel::Table.new('foo')
bar = Arel::Table.new('bar')

foo.join(bar, Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin) # inner
foo.join(bar, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin) # outer

foo.join(bar, ???) # left
```

How can you join two tables if you want to produce a left join?

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://ruby.ryanbigg.com/post/1468788928/left-outer-join-with-arel

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```
foo.join(bar, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin) # outer
```

Because LEFT JOIN = LEFT OUTER JOIN. Outer is an option.
See [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=53046)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a full example with rails models for anyone that wants to see.

Took me a couple of hours to figure out so I thought I would share with the world

This assumes you have one model called `RssFeed` and another called `RssFeedUser` which is a join model for a has_many :through for a model called `User`

```
RssFeed.find_by_sql(
  RssFeed
    .arel_table
    .join(RssFeedUser.arel_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
    .on(RssFeed.arel_table[:id].eq(RssFeedUser.arel_table[:rss_feed_id]))
    .where(RssFeedUser.arel_table[:user_id].eq(nil))
    .project('rss_feeds.*')
)
```