# Arel left outer join on second level table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

`A.joins(b: :c)`

but I want the (b: :c) to be  b.left_outer_join(:c)

any ideas please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to left join with Arel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475058/how-to-left-join-with-arel)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by manually appending the `b` LEFT OUTER JOIN with `c`:

```
a = A.arel_table
b = B.arel_table
c = C.arel_table

a
  .join(b)
  .on(a[:id].eq(b[:a_id]))
  .join(c, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)
  .on(b[:id].eq(c[:b_id])).to_sql
```

Which gives

```
SELECT
FROM "a"
INNER JOIN "b" ON "a"."id" = "b"."a_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "c" ON "b"."id" = "c"."b_id"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or...

```
b = B.arel_table
c = C.arel_table

join_on = b.create_on(b[:c_id].eq(c[:id]))
bc_join = b.create_join(c, join_on, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin)

result = A.joins(b).joins(bc_join)
```

Comment: `result` can be simplified to `result = A.joins(b, bc_join)`. Additionally you could just construct an outer join e.g. `Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(c,c.create_on(b[:c_id].eq(c[:id])))`

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using mostly high level `ActiveRecord` methods (The only `Arel` we actually uses is to simply return the join)

```
A.joins(:b,B.left_joins(:c).arel.join_sources)
```

Resulting Query is the Same:

```
SELECT
  "a".*
FROM 
  "a"    
  INNER JOIN "b" ON "b"."a_id" = "a"."id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "c" ON "c"."b_id" = "b"."id"
```